# Chef print out output of command ran in chef recipe

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I have a chef recipe that I need to modify, I would just like to see the output of a command.

```
bash 'Execute my script' do
  user 'root'
  cwd  '/'
  code <<-EOH
    cmd_stdout=$(echo 'hi')
    echo $cmd_stdout
  EOH
end
```

When I converge my chef kitchen, this script runs. I just don't see any output. Whats the best way to get to see "hi" in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using [execute](https://docs.chef.io/resource_execute.html) with `live_stream` set to true. It would be something like the following:

```
execute 'apache_configtest' do
  command <<-EOH
    cmd_stdout=$(echo 'hi')
    echo $cmd_stdout
  EOH
  live_stream true
end
```